# Feed a stream into Uri

Tags: c#, tcp, windows-runtime, udp, streaming

I am using the [MJpegDecoder from Coding4Fun](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder) to decompress a motion-jpeg stream in a windows runtime based app.

For a project I need to compare TCP- with UDP-transmission. The decoder expects a URI to the mjpeg source (for TCP streams it is *http:// IpAdress : PORT*). now with message based UDP I was thinking about providing a stream in which I write the single messages.

Question is:

Is it possible to get the Uri to an in-memory stream, without writing it to a temporary file before?

Comment: If it's open source, why not just enhance it to support what you need?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not generally possible because a URI doesn't have any control over how it is used.

If you decided to create a URI scheme which references an object in memory, that would be possible, but the client processing your URI would have to support it as well.

Specifically, MJpegDecoder only supports http based off of the body of ParseStream:

```
public void ParseStream(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    // snip
}
```